Why factor scores correlated with variables do not equal loadings?
I am trying to understand the following:
I have three variables (x1, x2, x3) on which I did PCA and EFA (principal axis factoring) in SPSS to get one component/factor.
If I do PCA and I calculate factor scores (regression method), which I call variable "F", then: Cor(x1, F)=component loading and the same for x2 and x3.
If I do the same with PFA, then I obviously get different loadings and factor scores, but also:
Cor(x1, F) is no longer equal to the loading (but only approximately).
Could someone please explain why this is so?
Correlations (n=12):
x1-x2: 0.310

x2-x3: 0.153

x1-x3: 0.529

Output:
Component loadings (PCA):

x1: 0.863;
x2: 0.564;
x3: 0.790

Cor(x, component scores) reproduce exactly the component loadings.
Factor loadings (PFA):

x1: 0.956, x2: 0.313, x3: 0.548

Cor(x, Factor scores) do not reproduce the factor loadings, but:
Cor(x1, F) = 0.998
Cor (x2, F) = 0.327
Cor (x3, F) = 0.573

Output SPSS when calculating factor loadings: "Attempted to extract 1 factors. More than 25 iterations required (convergence=0,006). Extraction was terminated".

The short answer is because they are different techniques. But tt would be easier to give a more comprehensive  answer if you provided the output, and the correlation matrix you are analyzing.

I added input correlations and the output from PCA and PFA. Hope this explains it better! Thanks!

I've tidied the formatting. Your N was 12?!!

Answer
I'm not sure what good you can get out of a factor solution constructed from such a small sample size. Factor analysis usually requires a fairly large sample, and this is especially the case when you have inequality in your loadings like you do (Costello & Osborne, 2005). I'm not sure what you can do with EFA-wise with such a small sample, so I wouldn't be able to suggest anything as a fix to this.
I'm guessing this is also why you get this spooky message from SPSS, which should have been a hint that something was perhaps wrong. The message is essentially telling you that your EFA solution is unusable.

Output SPSS when calculating factor loadings: "Attempted to extract 1 factors. More than 25 iterations required (convergence=0,006). Extraction was terminated".

By the way, I think you mean "PAF" (principal axis factoring) and not "PFA", but that is a more minor point.
References
Costello, A. B., & Osborne, J. (2005). Best practices in exploratory factor analysis: Four recommendations for getting the most from your analysis. Practical Assessment, Research, and Evaluation, 10(7). https://doi.org/10.7275/JYJ1-4868
